# Working with shell scripts on hp-ux and need to convert time to epoch using date command. How to solve bad format character -s error?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, epoch, hp-ux

To Work on few shell scripts and I need to get the time in terms of epoch in hp-ux

I tried using

```
date +%s
```

but i got bad format character - s error
i am allowed to use -u and -a options with date command in the environemnt

Comment: How about using `perl`?

Comment: i tried perl but i dont have DateFormat library and TimePiece library is not installed. and i dont know how to deal with the epoch conversion from GMT to EST-10EDT timezone while factoring in the daylight saving in the EST-10EDT timezone.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried perl but i dont have DateFormat library and TimePiece library is not installed. and i dont know how to deal with the epoch conversion from GMT to EST-10EDT timezone while factoring in the daylight saving in the EST-10EDT timezone.

- for GMT you can simply use

  ```
  perl -e 'print time'
  ```
- for local time you can use

  ```
  perl -e 'use POSIX qw(mktime); print mktime localtime'
  ```